# Regex in Python for matching contents inside ()

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to match contents inside the parentheses (one with "per contract", but omit unwatned elements like "=" in the 3rd line) like this:

```
1/100 of a cent ($0.0001) per pound ($6.00 per contract) and 
.001 Index point (10 Cents per contract) and 
$.00025 per pound (=$10 per contract)
```

I'm using the following regex:

```
r'.*?\([^$]*([\$|\d][^)]* per contract)\)'
```

This works well for any expression inside the parentheses which starts of with a `$`, but for the second line, it omits the `1` from `10 Cents`. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: What is your expected output from that text?

Comment: Are you printing the entire match or the group?

Comment: I want to return `foo per contract`, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for the second line, it omits the 1 from 10 Cents. Not sure what's going on here.

What's going on is that `[^$]*` is greedy: It'll happily match digits, and leave just one digit to satisfy the `[\$|\d]` that follows it. (So, if you wrote `(199 cents` you'd only get `9`). Fix it by writing `[^$]*?` instead:

```
r'.*?\([^$]*?([\$|\d][^)]* per contract)\)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use a less specific regex

```
re.findall(r'\(([^)]+) per contract\)', str)
```

This will match the "$6.00" and the "10 Cents."

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add one line, I want to omit things like "=" at the beginning of the expression

Comment: @JamesHallen In that case you could probably try something like `\(([^=)][^)]*)`, but I'm not sure what "things like "="" means specifically

Comment: @JamesHallen the suggestion in my commend should work for that

Comment: to make it more general could I do `[^(a-zA-Z|$|d)]`? So it should remove everything that doesn't start with an alphabet, a dollar sign, or a number

Comment: @JamesHallen that should be fine, but you don't need the pipes, and you need `\d` instead of just `d`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
r'(?<=\()[^=][^)]*? per contract(?=\))'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match the output you specified in your comments:

```
re.search('\((([^)]+) per contract)\)', str).group(1)
```